# How To Display Wifi List Promise Values React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using the react-native-wifi-reborn package to get a list of all nearby wifi points. How do I get the list out of the promise? I've looked at one solution and it uses a class, but where my app calls the function to get the list, it isn't in one.

```
const MainScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    requestFineLocationPermission();

    WifiManager.setEnabled(true);
    let wifiList = WifiManager.reScanAndLoadWifiList().then((data) => {return data});

    console.log(wifiList);

    return (

        <Layout style={styles.container}>
                
                ......

        </Layout>
    );
}

export default MainScreen;
```

When wifiList is logged, the output is `{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of a React functional component, which is an simpler way to define a React components compared to using classes. See more info in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components).

In your case, your component not being updated and re-rendered with the new `wifiList` data, because in your current code, you are not updating the component state at all:

```js
    let wifiList = WifiManager.reScanAndLoadWifiList().then((data) => {
      return data
    });
```

In this case, you are returning `data` result in a promise, but you are not using it to update the component state, and you aren't using `await` neither to retrieve the promise result. So you are actually assigning a Promise reference to `wifiList`, not the promise `data` result.

To correctly update the state on a functional component, you can use the [React hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) [useState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

The result would look something like:

```js
const MainScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    requestFineLocationPermission();

    const [wifiList, setWifiList] = useState(/* initialValue */); // you may provide an initial value (optional, defaults to undefined)

    WifiManager.setEnabled(true);
    WifiManager.reScanAndLoadWifiList().then((data) => { 
      // update the state here
      setWifiList(data);
    });

    // this will log the initialValue 'undefined' the first time, 
    // then after state is is updated, 
    // it will log the actual wifi list data, resolved by 'WifiManager.reScanAndLoadWifiList()'
    console.log(wifiList);

    return (

        <Layout style={styles.container}>
                
                ......

        </Layout>
    );
}

export default MainScreen;
```